# How use views exposed filters with taxonomy and panels

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I need some help with the use of contextual and exposed filters with taxonomy terms views using panels.

Context:

1. I have a panels taxonomy page overriding drupal default page.
2. In this page I have a views content pane display listing nodes with contextual filter set to "has taxonomy term Id" with type "taxonomy term id from URL" and "limit terms by vocabulary".
3. In "filter criteria" section I have a content type filter and the most relevant for my case, an exposed filter: "Content has taxonomy term", "is one of... allow multiple selection..." the usual.
   4- In Pane settings: Use panel path, set to "Yes".

The idea behind this is to have a taxonomy views pane showing results with exposed filters in the panel page. I.E: The user go to "animales/aves" URL and see as expected all the nodes from a content type categorized as "aves". The problem here is when the user try to filter to another animal category. In my example, the view give me no results. The URL change from animales/aves to this: animales/aves?tid[]=1 (or other id) but allways I get an empty view, except if I select back the exposed filter for "aves".

Any help?

Drupal 7.41
Ctools 7-1.9, Panels 7-3.5, Views 7-3.13

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you did this already under the "MORE" section.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it seems that makes no difference.

Behind that, what I found is that "Argument input" set to "From context > Require: Term id of first term" make the view work.